# How to compute holomorphic differentials on translation surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to compute a basis for $\Omega(W)$ for a translation surface $W$ of genus $3$. How does this work?

Explicitly I am considering the quaternion origami, which may be found in Herrlich's Paper "Introduction to Origamis in Teichmüller Space", section 5.

I know that $\Omega(W)$ is 3-dimensional, but I don't know, how to find differentials on $W$.